# Server closed connection unexpectedly when knitting in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

When I try to knit the default R Markdown file, I get this error:

> Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.
> Execution halted

For reference, this is how the default markdown file looks like:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Name"
date: "4/28/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 0):

Updated all the packages and now it works.